# Deployment success but can't send pictures

Tags: chat

Deployment success but I can't send pictures.
https://docs.openim.io/zh-Hans/guides/gettingStarted/imSourceCodeDeployment

```
sudo make start
===========> Starting openim

[success 0309 16:33:07]==> Configuration and example files operation complete!

Pre Starting OpenIM services
Preparing to start OpenIM Tools...
Starting tool ncpu...

Starting binary ncpu...
16
Service ncpu started successfully.
Starting tool component...
Starting PATH:open-im-server/_output/bin/tools/linux/amd64/component...
Specifying config: open-im-server/config
Starting binary component...
Checking components round 1...
Mongo connected successfully
Redis connected successfully
Minio connected successfully
Zookeeper connected successfully
Kafka connected successfully
All components started successfully!
Service component started successfully.
All tools started successfully.
Pre Starting OpenIM services processed successfully
```